# Switch to a view controller in a different tab after user performs action

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have the following storyboard in an application I am working on:

[image: View of my storyboard]

At the root, I have a Tab Bar Controller. It links to two View Controllers.

The first View Controller to display a newsfeed with pictures uploaded by the user (the one at the bottom in the storyboard).

The second View Controller serves to initiate the taking of a picture and attach some data to it. In the last step (top right), when touching "Save" in the right item of the Navigation bar, I want the user to be redirected to the newsfeed View Controller passing it some data.

I tried using a segue and it works. The data are passed to the newsfeed but the wrong tab is selected. I changed the selected tab using

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

But by tapping on the second tab again, things are messed up. I can see the newsfeed instead of the taking a picture screen. If I tap again, it crashes.

At some point I thought I may have got the wrong storyboard and should have implemented a TabBar in my newsfeed and handle the taking picture as a modal view.

Would you know any clean way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a normal segue, which **adds** the destination controller to the stack. To do what you are trying to the best way should be to use an unwind segue. This is a rough sketch of what you need to do:

• Declare an unwind segue action in the `NewsfeedController` like `(IBAction)unwindFromPictureSaved:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue`;
• Connect your "Save" button in your `SavingPictureController` to the "Exit" icon in the storyboard and select the previously defined method;
• In the newly created unwind segue define its identifier with something like `SavedPictureSegue`;
• Define the data to be passed in `SavingPictureController`'s header with something like `@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) id passedData`;
• In `SavingPictureController` implement

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SavedPictureSegue"]) {
        _passedData = // Your data here
    }
}
```

• In `NewsfeedController` now implement the previously defined method and fetch the data from `(SavingPictureController *)segue.sourceController`. Be sure to `#import "SavingPictureController.h"`.

Comment: Thanks @Davide ! You put me on the right track. I then noticed that the default behaviour is to search for the View Controller answering the unwind segue in the different children VCs or back to the parent who will call in turn its different children VCs. Because in my case, the 'NewsFeedController' is after a 'NavigationController', when the 'TabBarController' searched, it didn't find it. As a result I created a subclass of 'TabBarController' and overwritten the method 'viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:fromViewController:withSender:'

Comment: I thought it would have found it anyway since the call should go up to the `UITabBarController` which asks its children where the other `UINavigationController` is which also asks to its children where the `NewsfeedViewController` was...

Comment: Having tested it the second part does not happen. At least in my case

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Davide, I created a subclass of TabBarController and implemented the method below:

```
// Find the appropriate controller to answer to an unwind segue
// For each child view controller
// Checks if it is a Navigation Controller
// If it is check its children view controllers
// Return the first view controller that answers the unwind segue
// This because I assumed the default behavior is just to check one level up (in this case, it would have stopped at the NavigationController)
// Based on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-CCVC-SELECTING_A_CHILD_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TO_HANDLE_AN_UNWIND_ACTION
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController withSender:(id)sender {
    BOOL resChildren, res;
    for(UIViewController *controller in self.childViewControllers) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            for (UIViewController *childController in controller.childViewControllers) {
                resChildren = [childController canPerformUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];
                if (resChildren) {
                    return childController;
                }
            }
        }
        res = [controller canPerformUnwindSegueAction:action fromViewController:fromViewController withSender:sender];
        if (res) {
            return controller;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then in the unwind method of the 'NewsFeedController" it is necessary to set the correct index to see the controller with something like:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

I uploaded a demo on github at https://github.com/kintso/unwindSegueWithTabBarControllerAndNavigationController